# Bits is not derived from Num?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Trying to compile data-memocombinators 0.4.3, got the following error:

```
Data/MemoCombinators.hs:119:10:
    Could not deduce (Num a) arising from a use of `IntTrie.apply'
    from the context (Ord a, Bits a)
```

I think `Bits` used to be derived from `Num`. Perhaps it was bad and the dependency was removed, but now the package is broken. Is there any known fix for this? Perhaps I'm using a bad version of something?

I have added `Num a` to the function signature in my copy of the package for the time being, but this can't be right in the long term.

I'm using GHC 7.6.1, base is 4.6.0.0.

Comment: In the long term, you should raise an issue with the package maintainer, so the issue gets fixed for everyone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's [mentioned in the changelog for GHC 7.6.1](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/release-7-6-1.html#id9281219) (base 4.6.0.0).

> The `Bits` class does not have a `Num` superclass anymore.
>
> You can make code that works with both Haskell98/Haskell2010 and GHC by:
>
> - Whenever you make a `Bits` instance of a type, also make `Num` instance, and
> - Whenever you give a function, instance or class a `Bits t` constraint, also give it a `Num t` constraint.

See [GHC #5593](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5593) and the [mailing list discussion](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2011-October/016899.html) for more information about this decision.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've done (#2) just to be able to install the package.